# ElasticSearch/Kibana fields on update of document

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm very new to ES. I'm using https://github.com/dariusk/corpora/blob/master/data/humans/us_presidents.json as a learning set.

At first I entered this in Dev Tools tab in Kibana:

```
POST /presidents/president/1
{ "bo" : 
        {
         "website":"",
         "startdate":"2009-01-20",
         "role_type_label":"President",
         "enddate":"2013-01-20",
         "description":"President",
         "district":null,
         "phone":null,
         "title":"President",
         "congress_numbers":[
            111,
            112,
            113
         ],
         "title_long":"President",
         "current":false,
         "person":{
            "name":"President Barack Obama [D]",
            "firstname":"Barack",
            "twitterid":null,
            "middlename":"",
            "gender":"male",
            "bioguideid":"O000167",
            "namemod":"",
            "birthday":"1961-08-04",
            "link":"https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/barack_obama/400629",
            "youtubeid":null,
            "sortname":"Obama, Barack (President) [D]",
            "lastname":"Obama",
            "gender_label":"Male",
            "osid":"N00009638",
            "pvsid":"9490",
            "nickname":"",
            "id":400629,
            "cspanid":null
         }
         ...
        }
}
```

Then I realized that if I want add more data about individual presidents, I should rather do this:

```
POST /presidents/president/1
{
         "website":"",
         "startdate":"2009-01-20",
         "role_type_label":"President",
         "enddate":"2013-01-20",
         "description":"President",
         "district":null,
         "phone":null,
         "title":"President",
         "congress_numbers":[
            111,
            112,
            113
         ],
         "title_long":"President",
         "current":false,
         "person":{
            "name":"President Barack Obama [D]",
            "firstname":"Barack",
            "twitterid":null,
            "middlename":"",
            "gender":"male",
            "bioguideid":"O000167",
            "namemod":"",
            "birthday":"1961-08-04",
            "link":"https://www.govtrack.us/congress/members/barack_obama/400629",
            "youtubeid":null,
            "sortname":"Obama, Barack (President) [D]",
            "lastname":"Obama",
            "gender_label":"Male",
            "osid":"N00009638",
            "pvsid":"9490",
            "nickname":"",
            "id":400629,
            "cspanid":null
         }
}
```

OK, so ES accepted the update fine.

But now, when I go to Management / Index Patterns in Kibana, I see both `person.lastname` and `bo.person.lastname` as fields.

Why the previous field remained? Is this normal for ES to retain fields that are no longer in the updated document?

And obviously, apart from exceptionally funny ones, please no quips about today's election results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal, expected, behaviour for Elasticsearch.

ES, by default, will dynamically map the data you are inserting. When you index multiple objects under the same type in an index, all of these objects share the same mapping. The intention is to allow objects to be inserted that do not necessarily carry all of the potential fields of its type, and be inserted into the index anyways.

You can define a mapping yourself, either upon index creation, or by defining a new type for an index. Mappings can also be updated, with some caveats.

To see the mapping of the type in your index, execute the following:

```
GET /tk_file.2016/TK_FILE/_mapping
```

Your response will look like this:

```
{
   "presidents": {
      "mappings": {
         "president": {
            "properties": {
               "bo": {
                  "properties": {
                     "congress_numbers": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "current": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                     },
                     "description": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "enddate": {
                        "type": "date"
                     },
                     "person": {
                        "properties": {
                           "bioguideid": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "birthday": {
                              "type": "date"
                           },
                           "firstname": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "gender": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "gender_label": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "id": {
                              "type": "long"
                           },
                           "lastname": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "link": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "middlename": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "name": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "namemod": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "nickname": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "osid": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "pvsid": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           },
                           "sortname": {
                              "type": "text",
                              "fields": {
                                 "keyword": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "role_type_label": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "startdate": {
                        "type": "date"
                     },
                     "title": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "title_long": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "website": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "congress_numbers": {
                  "type": "long"
               },
               "current": {
                  "type": "boolean"
               },
               "description": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "enddate": {
                  "type": "date"
               },
               "person": {
                  "properties": {
                     "bioguideid": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "birthday": {
                        "type": "date"
                     },
                     "firstname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "gender": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "gender_label": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "id": {
                        "type": "long"
                     },
                     "lastname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "link": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "middlename": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "namemod": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "nickname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "osid": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "pvsid": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     },
                     "sortname": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "fields": {
                           "keyword": {
                              "type": "keyword",
                              "ignore_above": 256
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               },
               "role_type_label": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "startdate": {
                  "type": "date"
               },
               "title": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "title_long": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               },
               "website": {
                  "type": "text",
                  "fields": {
                     "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Notice here that you have a set of mappings for the `bo` object and its related sub-fields, as well as having a mapping for each field of your subsequent document. This is the effect of the dynamic mapping.

To disable this mapping flexibility, you can disable dynamic mappings explicitly, and defining the structure of the document yourself, including its datatypes. Perhaps you want the `bioguideid` to be an integer instead of text, as it is defined in the current mapping? I direct you to the [Mappings API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html).